# Ckeditor white screen in full mode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I use skeditor button to reveal the full screen is my page becomes a white box in top right and only have a couple of links and all of their output to this regime only helps refresh the page. Who can faced with the phenomenon and knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which browser and version of CKEditor are you using?

Comment: 4.5 in all browser